# MAX function not working on date with format dd/mm/yyyy in Google Sheets (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I'm using Google sheets and the `MAX()` function works only on dates with format `mm/dd/yyyy`. How to get the `MAX()` of date with format `dd/mm/yyyy`?|

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBu4W.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Excel (or Sheets) it tries to parse strings into dates, but can be a bit hit or miss (more miss) when you use a format different to what the machine you are entering it on is set to e.g. yyyy/mm/dd vs dd/mm/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy vs mm/dd/yyyy.

Firstly, to check if a date was correctly parsed, try adding a day to it. in your example, in B2 enter `=A2+1` and you should get an incremented date. If you get an error it means it's a string, not a date. To use the dates, you need to parse it yourself. In your specific example try next to your original date column `=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2))` and use that for subsequent calculations.

Comment: Actually, the problem is getting last login of customers. I'm using the formula`=MAX(IF(Sheet2!A2:A8 = I2, Sheet2!E2:E8))` (Sheet2 contains login times of all customers, column A is customer id, column E is login date). So, I think I will convert column E (dd/mm/yyyy) to column F (mm/dd/yyyy) with your formula, then replace column E by F. Thanks